# Remove accout in cli

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, address, linux

How can i remove an account in the cli version on linux?

I am created a "disposable" one with `account new`, but i can't find out how to remove it.

And if i create a new sub-address, it is possible to remove it?

**Edit #1:**

I removed the wallet file, and recover it from the seed, and i got the primary account only. I checked the secondary account's seed, and it is the same as the primary. Can someone explain how the account work?